# Can a sentence have two verbs of same type - for example "is"?

Tags: grammaticality

I found the following sentence in a book.

> A good way of figuring out what a function **is** doing **is** to type
>   it without the parentheses.

Is this correct way of writing?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is correct, you should add a "," after "doing" or you can simply say: "A good way of figuring out what a function does, is to type it without the parentheses.

Comment: I don't believe it's a rule to add the comma as you have described. The first part of the sentence all the way through and including "doing" is the subject, and since it reads clearly as written, I wouldn't personally add a comma. One reference: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/03/ (bottom of the page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can, although the two instances in your example are not exactly of the same type. The first *is* is a form of the function verb *be*, (it forms the present progressive of *do*), and the second is a form of the lexical verb *be* (here a verb in its own right).

Answer (score 1):

You try breaking it in parts and replace one part by a pronoun.

> What **is** the function doing?
>
> A good way of figuring out *that* **is** to type it without the parentheses.

Another example can be:

> What he does does not look good to me. (*That* doesn't look good to me.)